# API controller MVC 4 - return type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

in the HTTPGet API method, it seems like by default it will return the object in XML format. How can i make it to return in JSon format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASP.NET Web API has a built-in content negotiation, you just need to specify in your HTTP request's [Accept](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p3-payload-19#section-6.1) header field that you want `json` instead of `xml`.

You can start to learn more about content negotiation in [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2012/04/19/asp-net-web-api-how-content-negotiation-works.aspx).

Comment: thanks...  btw, do you know the proper way to do integration test on ApiContoller?

Comment: @Dr.jacky I can't add sample code because setting the accept header varies for each client. So without knowing which type of client are you using (AJAX, HttpClient, etc.) it's hard to help.